# Sending recipent specific emails

Tags: php

I have a situation.

I am a beginner at programming. I want to send an email to users based on a list of $to array. If $to has similar array elements then all the data is sent to one user. But if $to has different elements, then the data will be sent to the different elements of the $to array with $to specific data.

Please help me out.

Below is the code :- i have an array of $to. I need to separate emails based on the number of unique elemets in $to.

```
    if ($category!="Tool"){  
        $accessEmailBody = "\n<p>Please provide $reqFName $reqLName ($reqWinID) access to the following as per attached approval: </p>\n<blockquote>";
        $accessEmailBody = "<p>Hello $displayname ,</p>$accessEmailBody\n\t<ul>";
        foreach (array_values($wgs) as $wg) {
            list($wgName, $wgCategory, $wgId) = $wg;      
                if ($to == ''){
                    $to = $current->getWgEmailByCatID($wgCategory);
                }  
            $accessEmailBody .= "<li>";
            $accessEmailBody .= "(". trim($current->getWgCateNameById($wgCategory)). ")";
            $accessEmailBody .= " $wgName</li>
            <ul>";
            $rows = $current->getWgDetails($wgId);

            while ($line = mssql_fetch_row($rows)){     
                $accessEmailBody .= "<li><b>".$current->getWgResourceType($line[0]).":</b> $line[1]</li>";
            }
            $accessEmailBody .="</ul>";
        }
        $accessEmailBody .= "\n\t</ul>"; 
        $accessEmailBody .= "\n</blockquote>\n<p>Thank you.<br/>CRALT Admin</p>\n".$body; 

        if (isset($to)){
            return mail($to, $subject, $accessEmailBody, $header);
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to add a lot more detail to this question. Remember that we don't know what your code looks like or what logic you are trying to follow. Try adding some relevant parts of your code, and examples of how you are expecting it to behave.

Comment: Similar/different in what ways? Please show examples of what you're trying to do. If you're a beginner, try to keep things simple, and use the array uniformly.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have posted some of the code.

Comment: @HiteshThakur What do you mean when you say that the array elements of `$to` are "similar"? Could you post an example of your `$to` array and what you would expect the behaviour to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic outline of what I think you need. Obviously you'll need to fill out the other fields of the email function itself...

```
$to_array = array('john', 'jeff', 'frank', 'bill', 'frank');
$uniqueElems = array();

// this loop will make a new array of unique elements
foreach($to_array as $original_elem){

    if ( ! in_array($original_elem, $uniqueElems)) {
        $uniqueElems[] = $original_elem;
    }

} 

// now loop through the array of unique addresses and send them an email
foreach($uniqueElems as $addr){

    mail($addr,$subject,$message,$headers,$parameters);

}
```